# joi | how to turn off error message coloring and return it as plain text

Tags: javascript, joi

I have a problem returning joi's error message as a response from my server,
joi error message doesn't come back as plain text, it comes back as console characters with new lines and colors :

```
 {
    "error": "bad request",
    "message":"{\n  \"password\": \"mypass123\",\n  [41m\"username\"[0m[31m [1]: -- missing --[0m\n}\n[31m\n[1] \"username\" is required[0m"
 }
```

how can I get the message as plain text?